# Is there a way for mypy to warn about missing explicit typing when declaring a variable?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to setup *mypy* to warn me about all my mistakes in typing, but I have not been able to figure out the right config to get warnings/errors when I forget to add explicit typing when declaring a variable.

For example:

```
a = min([3, 5, 2, 4])
```

should warn me that I forgot typing in that line.

And this:

```
a: int = min([3, 5, 2, 4])
```

should say 'Success: no issues found'.

I would like this to happen every time and not only when *mypy* cannot infer the type on its own.

Is there a flag for this?

Comment: Even in cases where mypy can correctly infer the types?

Comment: if anything, this seems like something a linter should do rather than `mypy`.  what's the actual rule you want enforcing, maybe "all global bindings require explicit type annotation"?  what "mistakes" would this protect you from that other bindings, or even subexpressions, wouldn't also be affected by?  also, have you tried `--strict` mode

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, exactly. The point is to create a habit to make typing explicit every time.

Comment: @SamMason Yes, it should be something like that "all global bindings require explicit type annotation". I have tried `strict` mode but it does not do what I want

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to make mypy report an error if you don't include a type hint on every variable annotation. That kind of thing is considered an anti-pattern and so is explicitly not supported by mypy.

I'm a bit less familiar with how configurable linting tools such as flake8 are, but AFAIK they also don't support this kind of check. So if you want to mandate this sort of style, I'm afraid the only option left is for you to write your own linter.

I recommend that you instead focus on enabling the following categories of mypy command line flags/config values:

- [Disallow dynamic typing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#disallow-dynamic-typing) -- prevent your code from using the dynamic `Any` type, instead requiring everything to have an explicit type.
- [Disallow untyped definitions and calls](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#untyped-definitions-and-calls) -- make sure all functions, annotated or not, will be type-checked

The following flags may also be useful:

- [`--warn-return-any`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-warn-return-any) -- further disallow the use of Any
- [`--warn-unreachable`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-warn-unreachable) -- detect more cases of code not being type-checked
- [`--strict-equality`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict-equality) -- helpful when debugging certain unreachability issues

Both disallowing dynamic typing and making mypy more aggressive about making sure code does not go unchecked should help your ultimate goal of making sure everything has a precise type.

Note that most of the flags I mentioned above are not enabled by default when using `--strict`.

Answer (score 1):

@SamMason , --disallow-untyped-defs & --disallow-incomplete-defs mypy arguments can address this problem now.  you can refer their document for more details.

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#untyped-definitions-and-calls
I have added this in my vscode settings and tested , its working
[image]

I not passed the type hint for the second argument , it throws an error
[image]

Hope it could help addressing this problem

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.